# EF 6 .Include() optimization

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a large object that needs all of it's members loaded at all times.

```
rtrn.List = Context.Days
          .Include(x => x.Inspections.Select(y => y.Type))
          .Include(x => x.Inspections.Select(y => y.Subtype))
          .Include(x => x.Inspections.Select(y => y.Inspector))
          .Include(x => x.Inspections.Select(y => y.Approver))
          .Include(x => x.Inspections.Select(y => y.OperatorAddress))
          .Include(x => x.Inspections.Select(y => y.Unit))
          .Include(x => x.Inspections.Select(y => y.RecordsAddress))
          .Include(x => x.Inspections.Select(y => y.InspectionAddress))
          .Include(x => x.Inspections.Select(y => y.People))
          .Include(x => x.Inspections.Select(y => y.CustomFields))
          .Include(x => x.Inspections.Select(y => y.Codelinks.Select(s => s.CodeSections.Select(q => q.Questions.Select(a => a.Answer)))))
          .Include(x => x.Inspections.Select(y => y.Attachments))
          .Include(x => x.Inspections.Select(y => y.Comments))
        .Include(x => x.Inspections.Select(y => y.ComplianceRecords.Select(z => z.Records)))
          .Include(x => x.Inspections.Select(y => y.CorrespondenceRecords))
          .Where(x => x.Inspector.Id == userId).OrderByDescending(x => x.DayDate).Skip(page * perpage).Take(perpage).ToList();
```

It takes a very time to load and I am looking for ideas how to speed it up.
Through my research I have seen suggestion of using `.Load()` method instead of includes so I tried that

```
var rtrn = Context.Days..Where(x => x.Inspector.Id == userId).OrderByDescending(x => x.DayDate).Skip(page * perpage).Take(perpage).ToList();

foreach (Day d in rtrn)
        {
            Context.Entry(d).Collection(x => x.Inspections).Load();
            foreach (Inspection insp in d.Inspections)
            {
                Context.Entry(insp).Reference(x => x.Type).Load();
                Context.Entry(insp).Reference(x => x.Subtype).Load();
                Context.Entry(insp).Reference(x => x.Inspector).Load();
                Context.Entry(insp).Reference(x => x.Approver).Load();
                Context.Entry(insp).Reference(x => x.OperatorAddress).Load();
                Context.Entry(insp).Reference(x => x.Unit).Load();
                Context.Entry(insp).Reference(x => x.RecordsAddress).Load();
                Context.Entry(insp).Reference(x => x.InspectionAddress).Load();
                Context.Entry(insp).Collection(x => x.People).Load();
                Context.Entry(insp).Collection(x => x.CustomFields).Load();
                Context.Entry(insp).Collection(x => x.Codelinks).Load();
                Context.Entry(insp).Collection(x => x.Attachments).Load();
                Context.Entry(insp).Collection(x => x.Comments).Load();
                Context.Entry(insp).Collection(x => x.ComplianceRecords).Load();
                Context.Entry(insp).Collection(x => x.CorrespondenceRecords).Load();

                foreach (CodeLink cl in insp.Codelinks)
                {
                    Context.Entry(cl).Collection(x => x.CodeSections).Load();
                    foreach (CodeSection cs in cl.CodeSections)
                    {
                        Context.Entry(cs).Collection(x => x.Questions).Load();
                        foreach (Question q in cs.Questions)
                            Context.Entry(q).Reference(x => x.Answer).Load();
                    }
                }

                foreach (ComplianceRecordBucket b in insp.ComplianceRecords)
                    Context.Entry(b).Collection(x => x.Records).Load();
            }
        }
```

That takes about 10 times longer based on my measurements. Can't say I am surprised but that leaves me with not knowing where tackle this.

Comment: Why you don't remove Lazy loading attributes from the model?

Comment: You mean `virtual` as in `public virtual EF.User.User Approver { get; set; }`? If so there aren't any. Hence why I need to use `.Include()`.

Comment: "large object | that needs all of its members loaded | at all times". That's three poor design decisions in one little sentence. Don't try to fix it by running separate queries. Bite the bullet and improve the design.

Comment: wasnt game to say it. but was thinking that Gert...

Comment: @GertArnold  Not disagreeing. BUT this query rolls up to an API and the client app needs that whole object that's just how it is. Need to work with the reality of the situation.

Comment: Even then... in each API there's a balance between chatty and chunky. But if the design is carved in stone, yes, executing Load statements could help, but not for each `Day` x `Inspection`.

Comment: If the query is for a client app, does the data need to be added into the changetracker, that is, will you be just sending the data on to the client and not changing it and saving it back to the database within the same context? If you arent saving within the same context, you could avoid the overhead of changetracking by adding AsNoTracking() after "Context.Days".

Comment: @toasties no it doesn't need to be tracked since saving happens during a different http request. `AsNoTracking()` did make the query a little faster.